Compactness of bounded index solutions of the Yamabe problem
Consider, a closed Riemannian manifold $ (M^n,g) $ , $ n \geq 3 $, with positive Yamabe invariant: $$ 0< Y(M, [g]):= \inf_{0<v \in H^1} Q_g(v),  $$ where $$ Q_g(v) =  \inf_{0 <v \in H^1} \frac{\int \frac{4(n-1)}{n-2}|\nabla v|^2+R_g v^2}{\big(\int v^\frac{2n}{n-2})^\frac{n-2}{n}}. $$
Define $\Phi = \{0< v \in H^1 : \ DQ_g(v) \equiv 0 , 
 \int v^\frac{2n}{n-2}  =1\}$ to be the set of all solutions to the Yamabe problem, with fixed volume 1. By the combined works of many authors, it known $\Phi$ is compact (in the $ C^2 $ topology, say) as long as the dimension is at most 24, and the higher dimensional positive mass theorem holds true. It is also true that the minimizing solutions in $\Phi$ form a compact set (by Lion’s concentrated compactness method, or Uhlenbeck’s renormalization procedure if M is conformal to the round sphere), and this is much easier to show. Thus I find it natural to ask whether or not the solutions in $\Phi$ with Morse index bounded by $N$ form a compact set as well. Brendle and Brendle-Marques have constructed a sequence of solutions blowing up in $C^0$ norm but it’s not clear to me (by the elaborate Lyapunov-Schmidt type construction) whether or not these solutions all have uniformly bounded Morse index. Appreciate if someone could point me to the literature, or outline how one might go about computing the index of the Brendle-Marques solutions.
